# tomcat Adress already in use error when no address is in use

Tags: jsp, tomcat, port

I've been trying to run my Apache Tomcat server on localhost to run my JSP project, and for some reason it gave me a JVM_Bind error saying that the port 8080 is already in use.

After I've changed the port, to 9876, I'm still getting the same error:

```
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:9876]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:723)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
```

So I checked in the cmd if there's anything taking up the port 9876, using the `netstat -an | findstr "9876"` command, and found nothing. What could possibly be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are two Ways to Handle This Error :

1. **Command to Check Port is Listening or not** : 
   `C:\>netstat -ano | find "9876"
   TCP    0.0.0.0:9876      0.0.0.0:0     LISTENING     26732`
2. **Change The Tomcat Port Number** : 
   go to apache--conf  then Open `Server.xml` file

   ```
    <Connector port="9876" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
          connectionTimeout="20000"
          redirectPort="8443" />
   ```

   Then Change the port number to 8089 or any number .Happy to help